# CollapsingToolbar overscrolls when scroll up

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to implement IU with `CollapsingToolbar` that contains `Toolbar`, `TabBarLayout` and some `View` between them (technically `View` is behind them). `Toolbar`, `TabBarLayout` should always be on screen and `View` should collaps and expand on scrolling.
So I have a layout structure like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        ...
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapseingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="131dp"
                android:layout_height="131dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                ...
                >
                <TextView  .../>
                <ProgressBar .../>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It works as I expected except one thing. When `CollapsingToolbar` is expanded and you try to scroll up (pull content down) it pulls all the content on `CollapsingToolbar` a bit down and then get it back.
Here ia a video:
[image]
So I'm wondering if it is framework bug or I did something wrong. And how to workaround this issue.